# Which one is easier to debug between theano and caffe?

Tags: deep-learning

I am investigating whether to use theano or caffe for convnets. I would like to know which one provides a better debug environment. In caffe, it seems you don't write any code just a config in protobuf - how do you debug the convnet then?

Comment: Related: [How hard is debugging with Theano?](https://www.quora.com/How-hard-is-debugging-with-Theano)